# Getting the latest message from a distinct user

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Suppose I have two users that have each sent two messages to a third user, like so:

```
This is the first message from user 1
This is the second message from user 1
This is the first message from user 2
This is the second message from user 2
```

I'm trying to select the most recent message from each user from my PostgreSQL database with this:

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user).distinct('message_from')
```

This gives me the first object it pulls from each user, I.E.

```
This is the first message from user 1
This is the first message from user 2
```

While I want the second.

I've tried `messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user).distinct('message_from', 'time_date').order_by(
        '-time_date')`  in order to sort them but this gives me all 4 messages.

How can I get the latest message from each individual user?

EDIT:

The model of `Message`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_form")
    message_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_to")
    message = models.TextField()
    files = models.ForeignKey(File, blank=True, null=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your Message model? Might be helpful.

Comment: I've added the code for the model in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to get the whole `Message` object, but you can put as many fields in `values` as you want to do it in one statement:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Message.objects.values('message_from').annotate(latest_msg=Max(time_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user).order_by('message_from',
        '-time_date').distinct('message_from')
```

will do what you want.